# How to insert items in CheckListBox in VB.2017 Windows Form in Design Mode?

Tags: windows, vb.net, checklistbox

Prior to VB.2017 I was able to insert items into a CheckListBox by just positioning the cursor after an existing item and hitting enter.

This no longer work in VB.2017. I can only add items at the end.

Is there are way to edit the items in a CheckListBox as it was done in previous versions of VB.Net?

Thanks

Comment: It appears that they have changed the design-time editor for String collections and that new editor is used anywhere that a collection of Strings is edited. The old one was just a multi-line `TextBox` while this new one appears to be an actual list of some sort. It might be a WPF `StackPanel` that contains individual `TextBoxes`. Not sure why they made the change but maybe they thought it was too easy to edit in the wrong place before. There doesn't seem to be any way to reorder items at all, so that seems a weakness to me.

Comment: you have to clear checkboxlist, and arange the items and fill it again.

Comment: This is really bad. We have many programs that use CheckListBoxes.some with 40 or so items.

Since you cannot even copy and paste the Item Collection this causes us to complete redo the CheckListBox in we want to re-order a single item.

Microsoft please change this back to the way it was.

Comment: The items you add in the Designer, you'll find in the `[Form].Designer.vb` as: `Me.CheckedListBox1.Items.AddRange(New Object() { ... })`. Easy to reach and copy or duplicate in code (what you should do).

Comment: I found that also. But it is very prone to error especially if you have a lot of items.

It was much easier to do it the old way.

Every time I upgrade to a newer Visual Studio it gets harder to do basic things.